# jQuery remove character from text

Tags: jquery, html, string, character

I have the following code:

```
$('#table1 .set2').each(function()
{
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

This brings back a range of %'s currently in an alert box.

```
99%
87%
12%
```

What I need to do is remove the `%` character so I am left with a number that I can use.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: can you not just do a simple `x.replace('%', '')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$(this).html()
```

to:

```
$(this).html().replace('%','')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fxKk5/)**

Comment: A further question - how do I convert this html to a number, so I can add them together?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this should work for you

```
$('#table1 .set2').each(function()
    {
        var number=$(this).html().trim().slice(0,-1);
        alert(number);
    });
```